# Carrying out a Wilcox test in Rstudio on a large dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe for which the row names are genes, and the column names are sample names. Each of the sample names is a string of letters and numbers, followed by either 'TissueA' or 'TissueB'. I need to carry out a wilcox test to test for differential expression between samples containing 'TissueA' in the title or 'TissueB'. How would I go about doing this? (I am new to coding so if explanations could be kept simple that would be great!)

Comment: Do you intend to perform a Wilcoxon test for each gene ?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should create a vector the same length of your sample number indicating if they are of tissueA or tissueB. For example, if you have 3 samples of tissueA and 3 samples of tissueB it should look like this:

```
tissue <- c("TissueA", "TissueA", "TissueA", "TissueB", "TissueB", "TissueB")
```

then you can use the apply function to do a wilcox for each row (each gene) in your data frame:

```
results <- apply(X = df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x)wilcox.test(x~tissue))
```

X = df is your dataframe. MARGIN = 1 is for applying the function to the rows of df. With x~tissue your are doing a wilcox test in your df as a function of the vector that distinguishes your samples into two groups.

This code will do what you are asking for, however if your data is from a high-throughput experiment there are dedicated packages for calculating differential expression of genes, such as DEseq2.

EDIT: how to create the tissue vector based on column names of your data frame

You will need to install the stringr library for this one

```
library(stringr)  
tissue <- str_extract(colnames(df), pattern = "Tissue.")
```

The point after "Tissue" in the pattern means that any character after "Tissue" is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! How would I create the vector for my dataframe, where I have hundreds of samples containing either 'TissueA' or 'TissueB' in their names?

Comment: you are wlecome! I've added as an edit a posible way to extract the tissue type from the column names of your data frame. If it doesn't work in order to help you any further I'd need some examples of how your samples are named